# Is there a Java "Windows 10" look and feel?

Tags: java, windows, swing

This is a simple question, I'm wondering : is there a Windows 10 look and feel for Java? When I use the following code

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

It changes the looks to something similar to Windows 98

[image: Windows 98 look]

Is that normal? I looked around and found [JGoodies Looks](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/looks/) but it looks like it's not supported anymore.

Thanks!

Comment: swing is also old fashioned ;-) if you start from scratch maybe javafx is a better solution for you, which has a more modern look and feel inside (not like win 10)